# Can CiviCRM be used in a HIPAA context?

Tags: contacts, civicase

I was talking to somebody over the weekend regarding a site that seemed a perfect match for CiviCRM -- including donations, event registration, contact/relationships, case management. When I mentioned that CiviCRM handled all of these things, their first response was that the case management features would need to be [HIPAA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Health_Insurance_Portability_and_Accountability_Act) compliant.

Has anyone used CiviCRM in a HIPAA context? If so, can you detail any special set up considerations and requirements that are needed?

Answer (score 2):

Mostly. See

https://forum.civicrm.org/index.php?topic=7788.0

AND

https://civicrm.org/blog/charlescampbell/civicrm-civicase-ehremr-crisis-response-system

The part about who views records wasn't implemented from within CiviCRM, but depending on the definition of "your personal records" in your context it could just mean page hit tracking from within drupal, since it records the logged in user.